# CSS Issue with Responsiveness, Not going into Full-Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created [this page](http://sso.messiah.edu) based on bootstrap and when I test it with http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/ the page goes into full-width mode, adjusting to the screen-size of the browser on the phone. However, when I do this on my real IPhone 6 (and also IPad), it does not seem to do this (both in Safari and Chrome) and I'm not sure why. Perhaps this behavior occurs because it automatically tabs into the Username field, thus zooming out? I attached a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: on this line "col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" you should use 
"col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the width is set to 50% because of the class col-sm-6.

Please add col-xs-12 to the div to the make its width 100%

Please refer to [Bootstrap's Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: Are you saying it should be changed to col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 ?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the viewport meta to the header of your page. It's quite important for mobile sites to control the zooming:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

More information is at Mozilla's MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Both your answer and the one by @Prem Anand were equally helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make the class on the parent div 'container-fluid'.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Adjust the bootstrap classes to:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@John I think the problem Is with the zooming Here, add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">` in the `<head>` tag, That should do the trick!